# How to count number of Corner Detected in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have implemented certain number of algorithms to detect corners in matlab like harris corner ,moravec corner ect..
Now my question is how to detect the number of corners detected.
In other words I want the count of number of corners detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB's Built-in function [`corner`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corner.html) has various functionality.

I have taken a sample image here

[image]

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZTWm.jpg'));

%//  fixing the corners detected indirectly by specifying quality level.
C = corner(im,'QualityLevel',0.2); 

Cno = size(C,1);
```

Output:

```
>> Cno

Cno =

 4
```

Or you could fix the no of corners directly:

```
rgbIm = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZTWm.jpg');
im = rgb2gray(rgbIm);
C = corner(im,3);  %// specifying maximum no. of corners

Cno = size(C,1);

figure;
imshow(rgbIm);
hold on
scatter(C(:,1),C(:,2),50,'filled');
hold off
```

output:

```
>> Cno

Cno =

 3
```

[image]

Comment: Wanted to know what did u mean by quality level

Comment: @bksumedha Zoom in the picture. The corner detection uses different algorithms to detect the corners. If you decrease the quality level you get more number of corners. similarly when you increase the value, you get less number of corners. Play with some images changing those values.. you will get it.

Comment: I have a image and have detected all red objects in that.But when i proceed for the next step i.e, the edge detection i get an output of only black color instead of giving the edges.Whats the problem here???

how to get my answer??

Comment: @bksumedha Would you be nice to post this as a new question with all necessary images and code?

Comment: r=im(:,:,1); g=im(:,:,2); b=im(:,:,3);
diff=imsubtract(r,rgb2gray(im));
 bw=im2bw(diff,0.18);
 area=bwareaopen(bw,300);
 rm=immultiply(area,r);  gm=g.*0;  bm=b.*0;
 image=cat(3,rm,gm,bm);
 axes(handles.Image);
 imshow(image);
  end

Comment: I=image;
Thresholding=im2bw(I);

axes(handles.Image);
imshow(Thresholding)


fontSize=20;
 
edgeimage=Thresholding;
BW = edge(edgeimage,'canny');
axes(handles.Image); 
imshow(BW);

Comment: @bksumedha, ok.. i'll try to answer this tomo